# c# String formatter with % placeholders?

Tags: c#, .net, event-viewer

As a project, I've been building a log parser.

One of it's capabilities is to parse and identify specific matches in Event Viewer files.

I have the implementation all working well, however I ran into a small roadblock.

When I match a specific EventRecord, I go and get the ProviderMetadata, which will have the event description.

My problem is that the event description uses "%1, %2,..." as placeholders instead of {1} that StringFormat uses.

Here is an example of a description:

```
%1 
Device is AAD joined ( AADJ or DJ++ ): %2 
User has logged on with AAD credentials: %3 
Windows Hello for Business policy is enabled: %4 
Windows Hello for Business post-logon provisioning is enabled: %5 
Local computer meets Windows hello for business hardware requirements: %6 
User is not connected to the machine via Remote Desktop: %7 
User certificate for on premise auth policy is enabled: %8 
Machine is governed by %9 policy. 
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832647 for more details.
```

As I might need to format dozens of descriptions I'm looking for a performant solution.
How can I format this string and replace these placeholders in C# ?

Thank you

P.S.: I don't know how many place holders a description has in advance.

Comment: "I don't know how many place holders a description has in advance." Well you mentioned `string.Format`, how would you use that if you don't know the arguments?

Comment: You can pass an array of arguments to be used.
The arguments itself will match the "description" to be formatted, including how many elements it has technically.
Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is by using [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"%(\d+)", m => 
    /* build the replacement for index Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value) */);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however wouldn't this work only for a single index? 
To which I would need to do some sort of while loop until there are no more placeholders matches correct?

Comment: No, it works for any number of indices, no while loop needed.